# Formatting a String in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsstring

I'm getting a response from webservice as a string like below one -

> brand=company%%samsung@@modelnumber=webmodel%%GT1910@@Sim=Single%%SingleSim@@3g=yes%%Yes@@wifi=yes%%yes(2.1 mbps upto)

I'm confusing that to format my response like below one -

```
brand=samsung
modelnumber=GT1910
Sim=SingleSim
3g=Yes
wifi=(2.1 mbps upto)
```

I've tried to remove the special characters `(@@ and %%)`

```
specialString = [specialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@@" withString:@"\n"];
specialString = [specialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%%" withString:@"\n"];
specialString= [specialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

My output was -

```
brand=company
samsung
modelnumber=webmodel
GT1910
Sim=Single
SingleSim
3g=yes
Yes
wifi=yes
(2.1 mbps upto)
```

How to remove unwanted words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use simple find and replace because there are parts of the original string you don't want.

Untested, but this will probably work:

```
NSArray *parts = [specialstring componentsSeparatedByString:@"@@"];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSString *piece in parts) {
    NSArray *pairs = [piece componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if([pairs count] > 1) {
        NSString *key = [pairs objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *values = [pairs objectAtIndex:1];
        NSArray *avalues = [values componentsSeparatedByString:@"%%"];
        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [avalues lastObject]]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", [result componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]);
// [result release]; // Uncomment if ARC is turned off
```

First splits by `@@` and iterates over array. Then splits by `=` to get key on left side (index 0). Takes right side (index 1) and splits by `%%` and uses last value.

Comment: Exception raising - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`

Comment: Hmmm... works perfectly with the sample you gave. Added a condition to fix the exception. What string caused the exception?

Comment: [result addObject:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [avalues lastObject]]];  Try it...

Comment: Prasad G: That's virtually the same thing, besides the fact using an init in that fashion would be very bad with ARC turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Trim like below it will work

```
NSString *strRes = @"brand=company%%samsung@@modelnumber=webmodel%%GT1910@@Sim=Single%%SingleSim@@3g=yes%%Yes@@wifi=yes%%yes(2.1 mbps upto)";
strRes = [strRes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"--"];
strRes = [strRes stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@@" withString:@"\n"];
NSRange rangeForTrim;
while ((rangeForTrim = [strRes rangeOfString:@"--[^%%]+%%" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    strRes = [strRes stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rangeForTrim withString:@"="];

NSLog(@"%@",strRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't write the code right away but here's what you gotta do:

- Replace all `%%` with `(space)`
- Replace all `@@` with `\n`
- Remove all words between `=` and `(space)`